# Changing multiple values in an XML column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I've got a column in a SQL Server table that is type XML. I want to change multiple values in the XML in a stored proc. I've already found the XML.Modify(...) command and have it working for a single value. Can I change multiple values in the XML in one update command or do I need to do it as multuple update commands?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use multiple `(xmlcol).modify` calls - you cannot update multiple bits at once, as far as I know.